# WordPress: Deleting User With Its Files In The Uploads Folder

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

How can I delete specific users and also remove all the files they've uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

This is a manual solution.  If you want to achieve this programatically, you need to write some code and present it in the original question if you need help.

http://example.com/wp-admin/upload.php?mode=list&orderby=author&order=desc

Replace example.com with your domain and then find the specific users uploades and delete them in bulk.

After that, go to the users section in WordPress and delete the user.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this programatically?

Comment: You'd either have to find a plugin or write a solution yourself.